# Como lidar com 2 pythons instalados (e.g. python instalado em Miniconda vs python instalado em WindowsApps)

Tags: python, instalador, anaconda

Eu geralmente uso o python por meio do Miniconda, porém devido a alguns projetos precisei baixar o node.js diretamente do site (sem usar o conda para isso) e ele instala a ultima versão do python pois não reconhece o que existe dentro da Miniconda. Com isso:

- Como eu lido com este python que foi instalado ao baixar o node a fim de utilizar somente o do Miniconda? (é só remover ele do PATH?)
- Quais as diferenças em baixar o node via `conda install` e pelo instalador direto do site?

Obs: Ao digitar `where python` ele me retorna:

```
C:\Users\henri\Miniconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\henri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

Comment: node.js que instala o python?

Comment: No instalador diz que se eu precisar de instalar alguns modulos, algumas ferramentas como Python e Visual Studio Build Tools precisam de ser instaladas, e como eu ainda nao sei exatamente do que vou precisar eu marquei para baixar